# Use System.in.read() repeatedly

Tags: java

New to programming, and I'm trying to create a "Guess the letter" game. The idea is that the first person presses a key, then the second person presses a key to see if she has guessed it right.

Here is my code:

```
package bookExamples;

public class GuessTheLetterGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{
            char answer;
            System.out.print("press a key and press ENTER:");
            answer= (char) System.in.read();
            char guess;
            System.out.print("Have a guess and press ENTER: ");
            guess = (char) System.in.read();
            if (guess == answer)
                    System.out.println("**Right**");

    }

}
```

It runs okay until the line "Have a guess and press ENTER:", then I tried to press a key again, the code has no reaction.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Is there an error? Or does it just stop? Did you type in a character followed by enter?

Comment: Based on the code you posted, once you enter a key and press enter, if the answer is correct, it will display a message. If not, the application will terminate.

Comment: `System.in` is in line-reading mode, so nothing is received by your program until you press Enter.

Comment: I would really encourage you to use a `Scanner` instaed of just `System.in.read()`. Then you can use the built-int method `nextLine()`. Also, your current setup will only allow one guess before terminating the program, you need to surround this in a loop.

Comment: Sorry guys, I pasted the wrong code, just edited the question.

Comment: Just to add what @Andreas said, Enter key will also generate characters which will be placed in standard input (represented by `System.in`). In Windows, Enter key adds `\r\n` (13 and 10 codepoints), and each of these characters can also be returned with you call `.read()`. To avoid headache use classes which are meant to read bytes as text (as characters) and will be able to properly handle line separators. Such classes are `Scanner` or if you prefer Readers like `BufferedReader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another one that matches original code intent but provides a Scanner and while loop until there is a match

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessTheLetterGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        char answer;
        char guess;
        boolean right = false;

        while(!right){

            System.out.print("press a key and press ENTER:");
            answer= (char) keyboard.next().charAt(0);

            System.out.print("Have a guess and press ENTER: ");
            guess= (char) keyboard.next().charAt(0);
            if (guess == answer){
                System.out.println("**Right**");
                right = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By casting a System.in.read() to char you are casting a byte from system to UTF-16. Therefore `char c = (char) System.in.read();` will only work for very limited input. 

I would recommend using Scanner to read in an entire line.

```
String answer = "A";

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String guess = "";

while(! answer.equalsIgnoreCase(guess))
{
   guess = scanner.nextLine();
}

System.out.println("CONGRATULATIONS YOU WON!");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning Java and wanted a way to make this program work using the commands I know (Scanner is more advanced).

As mentioned by Pshemo and Andreas, the System.in buffer has a 'linefeed' character (ASCII 10) still in it (assuming only a single character for 'answer' was entered).

By 'reading' that character the buffer is emptied and the next time System.in.read() is used it will take an entry as expected.  I added 'linFed' to clear it.

```
package BookExamples;
```

public class GuessTheLetterGame {

`public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{
        char answer;
        System.out.print("press a key and press ENTER:");
        answer= (char) System.in.read();

        char linFed;
        linFed= (char) System.in.read();

        char guess;
        System.out.print("Have a guess and press ENTER: ");
        guess = (char) System.in.read();
        if (guess == answer)
                System.out.println("**Right**");
}}`

Answer (score -1):

In your code there is no loop to keep guessing.  It's just a one shot deal.  To keep guessing, you need to repeat a part of your code.

```
package bookExamples;

public class GuessTheLetterGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{
        char answer;
        answer= 'A';
        char guess = '\0';

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(answer != guess) {
            System.out.print("Have a guess and press ENTER: ");
            guess = scanner.next().charAt(0);

            System.out.println(guess);
        }

        System.out.println("**Right**");
}
```

If you keep guessing until the answer is right, you no longer need the if statement.  The only thing left to keep the formatting correct, is to show the user their guess and start a new line.

NOTE: changed the code to use a scanner, and [`scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) to get one character at a time.

Comment: Calling `read()` means that you will also read the `\r` (on Windows) and `\n` characters inserted into the stream when the user presses Enter. Result: When giving a bad answer, the `Have a guess and press ENTER:` is printed multiple times.

Comment: Thank you, yeah, this way I can keep guessing. What I wanted, however, is to not fix the "answer", rather the first person can press whatever key she wants. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Updated to use Scanner.  and correct on the prompt being updated.

Comment: Pretend to be a dumb user (there are so many of them out there) and type `No I won't` at the prompt. Do you like how the program reacts?

Comment: At some point the OP has to clean up their own homework.  The key point is teaching the principles so they know what they have to do.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Question is reading one *char* at a time. You're suggesting to read one *token* at a time, but doing that also has weird behavior. Reading one *line* at a time would reduce such weird behavior. I guess my point is that while your suggestion is an improvement, it could be better by doing something else, not something more.